# Biblatex-sbl with first citation of something other than page number (footnote) for type article

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-sbl

In some fields, it is preferable when citing a footnote in another work, to cite the page number with the footnote number. In `biblatex-sbl`, if this is the first citation of an article, then it sees the `prenote` as something other than a page number and puts the whole page range in the footnote and then the `postnote` in parenthesis, which is not correct.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{customstyles.dbx}
  \DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{tdict}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=omit,fullbibrefs=true,sblfootnotes=false,citereset=chapter]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{temp.bib}
@article{article1,
   title     = {First Article Title},
   author    = {John Smith},
   journal   = {Journal Title},
   volume    = {3},
   number    = {2},
   year      = {2020},
   pages     = {15-30},
}

@article{article2,
   title     = {Second Article Title},
   author    = {John Denver},
   journal   = {Journal Title},
   volume    = {3},
   number    = {2},
   year      = {2020},
   pages     = {31-45},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill
Cite a normal page.\footcite[18]{article1} Cite a footnote.\footcite[20fn2]{article1}
Now cite a footnote first.\footcite[35fn3]{article2}

\clearpage
\printbibliography%
\end{document}
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

If the first citation is a page number, and then the second citation includes something other than a page number, the short citation is correct.

However, if the first citation includes a reference to a footnote (so that the `postnote` contains something other than just numbers), the full reference is wrong.

Is there a way to get `biblatex-sbl` to treat this as a page number?

I did find [this issue](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/918#issuecomment-581051609), but I am unsure what exactly to do. Do I need to manually define `passifpages`? It does not look like this command is natively defined in `biblatex`. And the comment about the definition of `PagesCheckSetup` having a trivial definition is also confusing because it looks like this command *does* have a definition in `biblatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could use `\passifpages` (as defined in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/918#issuecomment-581051609). The command is not defined in the `biblatex` core, so you have to bring your own definition. The idea is that this command normally does nothing normally (`\@firstofone` defines a macro that returns its single argument), but that is defined to hide its argument when `biblatex` checks if something is a valid page range (that's what the `\PagesCheckSetup` does).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=omit]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\let\passifpages\@firstofone
\PagesCheckSetup{\let\passifpages\@gobble}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Cite a normal page.\footcite[18]{sigfridsson}
Cite a footnote.\footcite[\passifpages{20fn2}]{sigfridsson}
Now cite a footnote first.\footcite[\passifpages{35fn3}]{aksin}

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Özge Aksın et al., “Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions,” J. Organomet. Chem. 691.13 (2006): 35fn3.]

If you cite many footnotes it might become tedious to always add `\passifpages`. There are two ways to make your life easier.

1. You can allow `f` and `n` as part of numbers with

   ```
   \documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
   \usepackage{polyglossia}
   \setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
   \usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}

   \usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=omit]{biblatex}

   \DeclareNumChars{nf}

   \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

   \begin{document}
   \null\vfill
   Cite a normal page.\footcite[18]{sigfridsson}
   Cite a footnote.\footcite[20fn2]{sigfridsson}
   Now cite a footnote first.\footcite[35fn3]{aksin}

   \clearpage
   \printbibliography
   \end{document}
   ```

   Technically this means that arguments such as `nfffnnfnfn` will now "count" as numbers, which is probably not too bad.
2. You can define a special command for `fn<number>`, say `\fn` that can again be hidden from the page checking code hidden.

   ```
   \documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
   \usepackage{polyglossia}
   \setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
   \usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}

   \usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=omit]{biblatex}

   \makeatletter
   \newcommand*{\fn}[1]{fn#1}
   \PagesCheckSetup{\let\fn\@gobble}
   \makeatother

   \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

   \begin{document}
   \null\vfill
   Cite a normal page.\footcite[18]{sigfridsson}
   Cite a footnote.\footcite[20\fn{2}]{sigfridsson}
   Now cite a footnote first.\footcite[35\fn{3}]{aksin}

   \clearpage
   \printbibliography
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Thanks @moewe! I don't think it is too tedious to use the `passifpages`, since as far as I could tell, this is only a problem when it is the first time you cite an article, not every time. Am I missing something? It seems to be fine when it uses the short citation. But I do like the defn of `\fn`.

Comment: @Paul I put `\passifpages` everywhere since I find it inconvenient to have to track manually which citation is the first citation. If you rearrange your text that might change. What's more there are related features that could in principle also mean that an `\ifpages` check is also applied in subsequent citations ("loccit" and "ibid"). This may not apply for your specific style, but may well become relevant if you switch styles.

Comment: For future reference, this problem also crops up when citing a theological lexicon or dictionary with `biblatex-sbl`. If the prenote is not a number, then it will put a comma after the abbreviation of the dictionary, which is wrong. I used the `\fn` from @moewe above, and that also fixes the theological dictionary problem. See https://sblhs2.com/2017/04/04/citing-reference-works-3-dictionaries-word/ for examples of how it is supposed to look.